# Getting Unknown error while accessing MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to get the chat messages from MS team channel using API.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages
```

It works in graph explorer and returns the list of all chat messages. But when I hit the same API within Postman it return the following error:
I have consented all the required permission in azure app. What else am I missing here. Has anyone faced similar issues?

Please let me know.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-04-20T04:01:46",
            "request-id": "e32d3a2e-001c-4478-8c9c-8d5ff0c5e125",
            "client-request-id": "e32d3a2e-001c-4478-8c9c-8d5ff0c5e125"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the token in POSTMAN? Also decode the token in https://jwt.ms and see if there are proper permissions in it?

Comment: Yes I decoded token in jwt.ms. All the required permissions are here in the token.

Comment: Also, I face the similar issue while i try to create chat using chat endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats. I'm accessing this api in Teams Tab code as well as trying in postman. None of it works. Only in graph explorer it works.

Comment: Are you using APP permissions? I mean are you using App context?

Answer (score 0):

list channel messages is under protected API in MS teams. Before calling this API with application permissions, you must request access. To get the access you have to apply [request access form](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR1ax4zKyZjVBmutzKVo1pVtUQ1VJMlNTNUdJV1FKTzVZSVU4MlMwTTdOTSQlQCN0PWcu)